# Xcode Transformation static library(.a) to Framework(.Framework)

Tags: xcode, frameworks, .a

I have a `Cocoa Touch Static Library` project（compile as a .a file）, i got a mission，create a `Cocoa Touch Framework` project, which has the same function as `Static Library`(same file, same  resource)

How can i achieve the goal quickly，there is some document explains how to transformation static library(.a) to Framework(.Framework) ?